# В CMD 2 условие выполняется, хотя при этом первое было ложным

Tags: cmd

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, при проверке есть ли файл в папке он хоть это и не верно выполняется условие где идет сравнение, а сравнивает он пустоту так как объем не был задан потому что файла нет. Как сделать так чтоб он не выполнял 2 условие, а просто проходил мимо него, потому что там 3 раза повторяется эта проверка.

```
for %%I in (C:\1c_backup\buh30_avto\1CV8_BUH30_Avto_%date:~6%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%2100.dt) do set SIZE_1CV8_BUH30_Avto=%%~zI

if  exist C:\1c_backup\buh30_avto\1CV8_BUH30_Avto_%date:~6%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%.dt (
  if %SIZE_1CV8_BUH30_Avto% GEQ 1000000 (
    echo Test6  >>%log%
    DEL C:\1c_backup\arhive\1CV8_BUH30_Avto_*.dt
    echo * Start COPY 1CV8_BUH30_Avto %date% %time% for C:\1c_backup\arhive>>%log%
    XCOPY  C:\1c_backup\buh30_avto\1CV8_BUH30_Avto_%date:~6%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%2100.dt C:\1c_backup\arhive\
    echo * END COPY 1CV8_BUH30_Avto %date% %time% for C:\1c_backup\arhive>>%log%
    set msg_1CV8_BUH30_Avto = "база скопирована" 
 )
)
```

Comment: `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`?